# Changing the name of pdf rendered in iframe tag in Browser Preview mode

Tags: html, angular, pdf, iframe

I received a pdf file from server and I need to change the name of it, right now it displays as hash.

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vYAv.png)

My code is below:

HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" title="my custom title" id="pFile"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
this.reportService.getReport().subscribe(res => {
const fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onloadend = () => {
const pdfElement = document.getElementById('pFile');
pdfElement.src = fileReader.result;

}
fileReader.readAsDataUrl(res);

});
```

Thanks in advance.